# I want to add same form below the first form when I have clicked on the add more form button

Tags: javascript, html

[When I will clicked on add more the same form will be display. I need help for developing the code for that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FFjC.png)

I have tried the code which is given in the stack overflow. But their is code for different fields. And I want the code for same field. So place help me out for that.

Comment: Welcome to the stackoverflow. Please add more codes to check what you want and what you have tried. [Please check how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The parameters to the addMoreForm method might be like: formName, fieldName, fieldType, formAction, formMethod etc to create a form through javascript, here are some links for creating elements in javascript ( is an element :-) ):

```
<input type="button" onClick="addMoreForm('the parameters come here*')" value="Add More" />
```

Comment: I have tried that but no use of that.